Jenkins slave on k8s failed to be started
I have setup a master Jenkins on k8s. It starts and works well.
Now when I tried to setup Jenkins slave on k8s and run a Jenkins job, it failed. Inside K8s, I can see a slave pod was created but the pod status is Error with below error message
kubectl logs -n jenkins kube-5jk3w
Dec 12, 2024 2:55:03 AM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager initializeWorkDir
INFO: Using /home/jenkins/agent/remoting as a remoting work directory
Dec 12, 2024 2:55:03 AM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager setupLogging
INFO: Both error and output logs will be printed to /home/jenkins/agent/remoting
Dec 12, 2024 2:55:03 AM hudson.remoting.Launcher createEngine
INFO: Setting up agent: kube-5jk3w
Dec 12, 2024 2:55:03 AM hudson.remoting.Engine startEngine
INFO: Using Remoting version: 3261.v9c670a_4748a_9
Dec 12, 2024 2:55:03 AM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager initializeWorkDir
INFO: Using /home/jenkins/agent/remoting as a remoting work directory
Dec 12, 2024 2:55:03 AM hudson.remoting.Launcher$CuiListener error
SEVERE: Connection failed.
io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.jakarta.websocket.DeploymentException: Connection failed.
        at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.client.exception.Exceptions.deploymentException(Exceptions.java:40)
        at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.container.jdk.client.JdkClientContainer$1.call(JdkClientContainer.java:188)
        at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.container.jdk.client.JdkClientContainer$1.call(JdkClientContainer.java:108)
        at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.container.jdk.client.JdkClientContainer.openClientSocket(JdkClientContainer.java:193)
        at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$3$1.run(ClientManager.java:614)
        at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$3.run(ClientManager.java:657)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(ClientManager.java:810)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
        at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:460)
        at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.lambda$connectToServer$2(ClientManager.java:313)
        at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.tryCatchInterruptedExecutionEx(ClientManager.java:324)
        at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:313)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.runWebSocket(Engine.java:788)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:543)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.implConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.container.jdk.client.TransportFilter.handleConnect(TransportFilter.java:185)
        at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.container.jdk.client.Filter.connect(Filter.java:80)
        at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.container.jdk.client.Filter.connect(Filter.java:83)
        at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.container.jdk.client.ClientFilter.connect(ClientFilter.java:99)
        at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.container.jdk.client.JdkClientContainer.connectSynchronously(JdkClientContainer.java:329)
        at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.container.jdk.client.JdkClientContainer$1.call(JdkClientContainer.java:157)

What is the reason of failure?
